# Do not able to build mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT.job(Recommendation on hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am using ubuntu 11.10.

I downloaded mahout_trunk using

"svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk"

in directory /opt.
After that i use "mvn install" command.

i already put linked-simple-sorted.txt in hdfs.
and also had put users.txt in input directory of hdfs.

After entering in /opt/mahout/core   directory.

when ever i try to build mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT.job using "mvn clean package".
It will not create any mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT.job .

i am only see mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar,mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT-job.jar,mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar.

when ever i try to run from this command:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /opt/mahout/core/target/mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -Dmapred.input.dir=input/input.txt -Dmapred.output.dir=output --usersFile input/users.txt --booleanData
```

I got the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli2/Option
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli2.Option
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

If i am try to run using this command:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /opt/mahout/core/target/mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT.job org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -Dmapred.input.dir=input/input.txt -Dmapred.output.dir=output --usersFile input/users.txt --booleanData
```

i got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: /opt/mahout/core/target/mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT.job
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
```

I tried a lot.but,do not come out from this error.

What i have to do?

your help will be appreciated.

Is there any another way to genarate recommendation on hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

You have it right there. Its the -job.jar file not .job

Comment: Thanx sean.Now it is successfully access (mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT-job.jar).

Comment: But,have 1 problem while running this command:            hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /opt/mahout/core/target/mahout-core-0.7-SNAPSHOT-job.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -Dmapred.input.dir=input/input.txt  -Dmapred.output.dir=output --usersFile input/users.txt --booleanData                                                        I got the error like:ERROR common.AbstractJob: Missing required option --similarityClassname

Comment: Well, that means what it says: you haven't specified that option.